# How to set custom markers (image) on GMSMapView

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I tried this

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin2.png"];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lati, longi);
marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
marker.draggable = YES;
marker.map = mapView;
```

but I did not get the image.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question but the problem with the question might be that it doesn't show any debugging effort.  What _do_ you get instead of the image?  Did you check that imageNamed actually returns an image (that marker.icon is not nil)?  Is pin2.png in your project?  Is it spelled exactly "pin2.png" (all lowercase)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing this line:

```
[mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
```